# iOS doesn't receive push from Azure Notification Hub

Tags: ios, swift, rest, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

In my iOS app I'm trying to add push notifications via Azure Mobile Services.

I have followed this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-ios-get-started-push/

But my app still receive no push notifications!

In the iOS dev center I registered App ID with Dev and Production push certificates.

Added Dev certificate (.p12) to Sandbox in the Azure.

I wrote POST function

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    var text = 'You\'ve just received a push!';
    var push = request.service.push;
        push.apns.send(null, {
          alert: "Alert",
          payload: {
              inAppMessage: text
          } 
        }, {
          success: function(pushResponse) {
          console.log("Sent iOS push:", pushResponse);
          response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : 'Push send success' });
        }, error: function(error) {
          console.log("Sent iOS push error:", error);
          response.send(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST, { message : 'Push send error: ' + error });
        }
    });
};
```

In the log I'm getting this everytime:

```
Sent iOS push: { isSuccessful: true,
statusCode: 201,
body: '',
headers: 
{ 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
   'content-type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
   server: 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
   date: 'Sat, 02 Apr 2016 18:27:42 GMT' },
md5: undefined }
```

Also, in the app I register for push:

```
if let client = self.azureClient {
    client.push.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken, tags: nil, completion: { (error: NSError?) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

I'm stuck and don't know what to do to make Azure send pushes to my app.

It would be great if anyone could explain me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

**UPDATED**

I've just found that in Notification Hub Debug tab when I try to broadcast push it shows that there is no registrations:
[image]
Despite the fact that Notification Hub Monitor shows, that there was some Registration Operations and Incoming Messages:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange, but when I replaced Developer Push Certificate with Production Push Certificate, my app suddenly began to receive pushes! Isn't it bug of Azure? Any guess why it happens?

Comment: Glad you got it working! If you are running through TestFlight or other ad-hoc distribution, it uses the production APNs channel. If you are running from Xcode, it uses the Developer/Sandbox channel.

Comment: Thank You! Therefore, it is quite strange, because I'm running app using XCode, and probably pushes should be received with Dev certificate, but it started to work well, when I replaced Dev certificate with Production.

Answer (score 0):

The alert key needs to be inside an aps object, like so:

```
push.apns.send(null, {
    aps: {
        alert: "Alert"
    },
    payload: {
        inAppMessage: text
    } 
}, .... );
```

Apple has a [page on push notification payloads](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html) with more examples.

Also make sure you are running your app on a device, as the simulator can't receive notifications.

If you still aren't getting notifications, see Apple's [troubleshooting page for push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html) or update your question.

Comment: Thank You for answer!
I'm running app on the device.
I've just added some details about Notification Hub Debug.