# How to debug a Test Send in Azure?

Tags: ios, .net, iphone, azure, push-notification

I am trying to setup a successfull push notifications between my .Net backend and ios client in azure. I followed [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-troubleshoot/#RuntimeDebugging) example to attach to my debugger and was able to get as far as hitting a break point in my visual studio in my pc by an action from my iphone with an iMac
[image]

The result object is neither throwing error nor returning results!

so, I've switched direction and now trying debug by only sending a Test Send in Azure (see pic). Again I get a message saying: "Successfully sent test message. Outcome {0 passed, 0 failed}" but there is nothing showing up on my iphone.
I think the behavior is similar to the one in code and solving one would solve the other:
A. Is it safe to assume that since I am hitting the breakpoint in code that my setup in Apple Developer is correct?
B. How would you figure out the strange message of 0 Passed and 0 failed!?

[image]

UPDATE #1 - Wesley McSwain:
thanks for answering. I was following this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push/) which had this swift registration:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
   application.registerUserNotificationSettings(
       UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound],
           categories: nil))
   application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
   return true
}
```

I can step through that code fine. btw the error?.description in the completion handler of this other method is nil:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    ClientManager.sharedClient.push?.registerDeviceToken(deviceToken) { error in
        print("Error registering for notifications: ", error?.description)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have been able to receive notifications last night. I went ahead and redid an entire walk-through of all apple-side installation steps using this tutorial: [Sending push notifications to iOS with Azure Notification Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/) then the azure-side of things using this: [Create an iOS app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started/) and [Add Push Notifications to your iOS App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push/).
That took care of the registering the app of the device successfully, which I was able to verify using the note of AdrianHall in this thread. 
But that wasn't enough. The Azure tutorials fell short detailing the steps needed in Xcode, which I found here: [[How To] Setup Remote Push Notification in iOS - Swift 2.0 Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HGPnuiLHM0&index=19&list=WL)
I didn't have to setup any "push notification" in Xcode or anything like that.

I hope this detailed answer will save you many hours of digging through.

Answer (score 2):

Another potential issue you are having is in registration.  There are three phases to a successful "test send":

1. The client registers with the PNS (in your case, APNS) and gets a device token
2. The client then registers with Notification Hubs, sending the device token (this is handled by the Mobile Apps client, which I see you have configured)
3. You can now send a test send from the portal (or elsewhere)

You can debug your client app to see if #1 is happening.  You can check within Visual Studio to see if your device is getting registered - go to the Server Explorer and double-click on your notification hub - it will bring up a window that both allows you to test send and shows the current registrations.  Once you have #1 and #2 working, #3 should "just work", assuming the right certificate is set up in your notification hub.

Comment: This azure setup is so faulty. The objective tutorial worked and the swift one doesn't. To answer your question, no, the mobile is not registered. Sometimes I am able to break at the C# the code in visual studio and most times I am not! Just too faulty, everything.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say if you've used a DEV or Prod certificate. If it was DEV, try using Prod certificate. It is reported often that DEV certificates have issues with Azure.
Check this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36377455/3126427)

I hope it helps.

Comment: hmmm... I used DEV. I'm fed up with it, but will try to use Prod.

Comment: actually that turned out not to be the case. Azure does warn that the free subscription may have "throttling" issue, but that's it. Enjoy the points! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling  "Push Notifications" in Xcode (Capabilities tab - make it ON) else you wont be able to receive notifications.

Comment: Actually that has not had anything to do with it. See my answer. That setting if you want to allow your app to "send" notifications. My issue was not being able to "receive"

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved after enabling above setting in 'Xcode' and I meant to receive push notifications and not to send.